# debian-installer doesn't detect partitions

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian

During Debian setup by using the minimal/netinst image, the wizard (`debian-install`) does not detect any partitions in my main HDD. Nevertheless they do exist when running `fdisk`. I have 2 NTFS partitions, a logic EXT4 partition and a logic SWAP, but I can't tell Debian how to use them. The volume is using a classic MBR partition table and the computer features old BIOS.

`blkid` prints:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="(random hex)" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="(random hex-01)"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="data" UUID="(random hex)" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="(random hex-02)"
/dev/sda3: UUID="(random hex with dashes)" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="(random hex-04)"
/dev/sda4: UUID="(random hex with dashes)" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="(random hex-05)"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="MULTIBOOT" UUID="(random hex with dashes)" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="(random hex-01)"
```

I've installed Debian (and other operating systems) many times without a problem. Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Same problem with Ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by removing SWAP and EXT 4 partitions in Window's Disk Management and by rewriting the MBR partition table with [fixparts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/).